# one by one insert row from one table to another using PROCEDURE and INSERT...SELECT

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Suppose I have two tables `tbl1` and `bak_tbl1` these tables are almost identical in strucutre.

I used to use `INSERT...SELECT` method to insert data from `tbl1` to `bak_tbl1` in bulk like this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_customer_sales (id,card_number,customer_name,customer_phone)
SELECT id,card_number,customer_name,customer_mobile FROM tbl_master_sales WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM tbl_customer_sales WHERE id=tbl_master_sales.id);
```

It worked fine with smaller batches of data, but it creates huge performance problems with millions of records.

So I want to know method that is as simplest as INSERT...SELECT if possible but inserts row one by one to another backup table `tbl1` and doesn't insert at once in bulk, so that system doesn't hang and I can work around the database while the procedure is pushing row one by one to `tbl1`.

Comment: What do you mean by "huge problem"? Performance issue? Error of some type? Incorrect result? And what indexes do you have on your tables?

Comment: @Renzo Performance issue,hangs the mysql backend and doesn't allow any other task until all rows are transferres

Comment: If you are just trying to make a backup copy of a table you can generate a script from your database, [example](http://www.dirkstrauss.com/how-to/script-table-data#.VczwaPlVhHz). If the only thing that is different on `tb1_customer_sales` is `customer_phone` rather then `customer_mobile` you can use a control F to replace all of the occurrences. It sounds like you are trying to create a new backup table for `tb1_master_sales`?